# Why does this loop not render all errors?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have this code that will loop through the validation and store the validation errors in `$error`, but my problem is now when I try to show that in other page it just show me the first error and not the others.

validate.php

```
foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {

           $_SESSION['error'] = $error;

             Redirect::to("teste.php");
        }
```

teste.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
  echo $_SESSION['error'];
  unset( $_SESSION['error']);
```

Comment: You are looping through errors but on the first error you are already redirecting someone O.o

Comment: i didn't understand Jordy

Comment: Have you actually started your session Ricardo? `session_start()`

Comment: yes, it output sthe error actually, but it only output me the first error, and not the others

Comment: Yes thats because you are putting the session error to the error and then directly redirects someone. It doesn't loop through all the errors. Even if you would remove the redirect it would still not work because you are overwriting the session all the time

Comment: and how can i do it? in validate.php now insted of doing the session and redirection, now i just have done echo to the $error and it output me that in teste page, "Service title is required.Service description is required."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through an array with errors in them but on the first error it finds it already redirects the user to the teste.php file. This way you will never be able to show all the errors. You should look at my solution.

validate.php

```
//Wrap an if around the session checking if there are errors, the class probably has that method as well.
$_SESSION['error'] = $validation->errors();

Redirect::to("teste.php");
//end if
```

teste.php

```
foreach($_SESSION['error'] as $error) {
    echo $error;
}

unset($_SESSION['error']);
```